# Overlay on 4 channel image

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have a image with 4 channels that i need to overlay it over a bunch of pictures. Over the pictures with 3 channels, the overlaying works great, but over the pictures that have an alpha channel, the background of the picture changes to black.

Original picture: http://img.blog.csdn.net/20130610074054484

Overlayed picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/50dtN.jpg

This is the code that does the overlaying:

```
void overlayImage(const cv::Mat &background, const cv::Mat &foreground, 
              cv::Mat &output, cv::Point2i location)
{
    background.copyTo(output);

    for(int y = std::max(location.y , 0); y < background.rows; ++y)
    {
        int fY = y - location.y;
        if(fY >= foreground.rows)
            break;

        for(int x = std::max(location.x, 0); x < background.cols; ++x)
        {
            int fX = x - location.x; 
            if(fX >= foreground.cols)
                break;

            double opacity = ((double)foreground.data[fY * foreground.step + fX * foreground.channels() + 3]) / 255.;

            for(int c = 0; opacity > 0 && c < output.channels(); ++c)
            {
                unsigned char foregroundPx = foreground.data[fY * foreground.step + fX * foreground.channels() + c];
                unsigned char backgroundPx = background.data[y * background.step + x * background.channels() + c];
                output.data[y*output.step + output.channels()*x + c] =
                backgroundPx * (1.-opacity) + foregroundPx * opacity;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Already had a look at [Adding (blending) two images using OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/adding_images/adding_images.html)?

Comment: Yes i had. Thanks anyway.The implementation of highgui's imshow fails to show any transparent images correctly. If i call imshow on the final image(after overlaying), the background is black. If i call imwrite on the final image, the image looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use 1-opacity for the background image. If the opacity of the forground image is 0, the opacity of your backgroundpixel will be 1 instead of 0 which it is before.

You have to calc the result opacity fpr both images which can be 0 for both too.

Claus

Comment: I was encoding and decoding the images at some point at the problem was that when i was calling decode, the second parameter was CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR and not CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED. Thank you Claus and Dobi. The answer can be closed now.